# Listener for Session Expiration in Spring

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I am new to spring security and using it for authentication. I am facing a issue that when the browser is closed or in case of any unusual failure the session expires but I am unable catch the event so as to get the clean up code executed.
I explore about it and found `HttpSessionEventPublisher` in Spring to capture `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` in `sessionDestroyed()` method but that is not called when I close the browser.

Request to suggest solution for the same.

Comment: I added a solution .Hope this helps and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [SessionManagementFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html) could help?

Or you can configure Spring Security to automatically redirect user if timeout occured: [Detecting timeouts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-session-mgmt) section.

Comment: SessionManagementFilter will help me trace and authenticate every request, but on closing browser no such request is send at server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the listener in the `web.xml`!

```
 <listener>
      <listener-class>
           org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
      </listener-class>
</listener>
```

But of course it detect only that the session is closed (because of an timeout or some explicite programmatic session destroy), but **it does not detect that someone close his browser**. This is because there is no http notification about a closed brwoser.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the **JQuery** to solve the browser closing problem ,

The **JQuery** will be ,

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});

$(window).on('unload', function(){
    //alert("unload");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Logout.html",
        //data: "message=" + message,
        dataType: "html",

        success: function(response) {

        },
        error: function(e) {
            //alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
});
```

In **Spring controller** ,

```
@RequestMapping(value="Logout.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public  @ResponseBody String logout(HttpSession session){

    System.out.println("Request Logout");

    // Do you work before invalidate the session 

    session.invalidate();

}
```

In **web.xml** add this , If you used HttpSessionEventPublisher to catch the session destroy event,

```
 <listener>
      <listener-class>
       org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
      </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i haven't tries this but what will happen if javascript is disable or if system crashes.

Comment: JavaScript must to be enabled.Today,  there is no web application without javascript.

Comment: @HyperLink Can this also be done using just JQuery without Ajax as our system just uses straight Spring MVC with direct client communication?  Thanks.